# Proof question: Show there is no homomorphism from $\Bbb Z_{16} \oplus \Bbb Z_{2}$ onto $\Bbb Z_4 \oplus \Bbb Z_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Prove that there is no surjective homomorphism from $\Bbb Z_{16} \oplus \Bbb Z_{2}$ onto $\Bbb Z_4 \oplus \Bbb Z_4$.

The book I'm reading starts off the proof with:

Suppose $\phi$ is such a homomorphism between the two groups, then $f: \Bbb Z_{16} \oplus \Bbb Z_{2} / \ker \phi \rightarrow \phi(\Bbb Z_{16} \oplus \Bbb Z_{2})$ is an isomorphism.  Therefore $\ker \phi = \langle (8,1) \rangle, \langle (0,1 \rangle),$ or $\langle (8,0)\rangle$.

How does the isomorphism imply that this is what the kernel equals?

Comment: Such an epimorphism must have a kernel of order two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that two isomorphic groups have the same number of elements.  So, $|\Bbb Z_{16} \oplus \Bbb Z_2/\ker \phi| = 16$.  So, $|\Bbb Z_{16}\oplus \Bbb Z_2|/|\ker \phi| = 16$.

So, $|\ker \phi| = 2$.

Comment: How did you get $|\Bbb Z_{16} \oplus \Bbb Z_2/\ker \phi| = 8$?

Comment: Excuse me, that should have been $16$.  Fixed it.

Comment: I guess I mean how did you find the quotient for the order of the factor group?  Wouldn't it depend on what $\ker \phi$ is?

Comment: I found $|\Bbb Z_4 \oplus \Bbb Z_4| = 16$, hence the first equation.  After I split up the quotient using Lagrange's theorem, I used the fact that $|\Bbb Z_{16} \oplus \Bbb Z_2| = 32$.

Comment: So for $H$ a subgroup of $G$, $|G/H| = |G:H| = \frac{|G|}{|H|}$?  Meaning the index of a subgroup equals the order of the factor group of the subgroup?

Comment: Yes, exactly!  Remember that the elements of a factor group are cosets, which are precisely what the index counts.

Comment: That makes sense, but why does the fact that the kernel only has two elements imply that these are the only possibilities?  I can see that using other subgroups increase the size of the kernel, but does this property imply because it's of order 2 or is this because of the nature of the particular sets used?

Comment: The groups listed are the only groups of order $2$.

Comment: I meant the only *subgroups* of order $2$, excuse me.

Answer (score 2):

The order of the domain is twice that of the range, so if the homomorphism is surjective, then the kernel has order $2$. That last sentence just listed all of the subgroups of the domain of order $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The cardinality of $Z_{16}\times Z_2$ is 32 and the cardinality of $Z_4\times Z_4$ is 16. Thus  the cardinality of the kernel of $\phi$ is 2 since it is surjective. The only subgroups of order 2 of $Z_{16}\times Z_2$ are generated by $(8,1), (0,1), (8,0)$.